# On the optimization of Oracle SQL (group by)

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

My current environment is Oracle 10g. My SQL statement is:

```
select t.pici pici,
      min(t.fdate) minfdate,
      max(t.rdate) maxrdate,
      count(1) countNum
from 
      test t
group by 
      t.pici
order by 
      minfdate desc
```

I also created indexes on pici,fdate,rdate. I need to page query this result,but it's too slow. This SQL statement takes 15 seconds.
There are about 10 million data in the table.
How do I optimize this SQL or other settings

Comment: This is nothing to do with Java.  Please tag your questions with **relevant** tags.  It will help you get answers sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to page query...

Your query does not have any filtering condition (`WHERE` clause), so it's including the entire table (all rows). Computing 10 million rows will take some time. No way around it.

This is not suitable for an interactive query. If it's the case, you'll need to rethink your strategy. Probably you'll need to precompute the query result into a temp table, or a materialized view (with indexes), and refresh the temp table every hour or so. You can't be running a 10 million rows query every time, probably with multiples users at the same time.

Having said that, you can still improve the query by using a "covering index", at least marginally. That is, creating an index that includes the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, and then the ones in the `SELECT` clause. The covering index you should use according to your example is:

```
create index ix1 on test (pici, fdate, rdate);
```

This covering index may allow the optimizer to skip reading the heap and only use the index, but it's not a sure thing; the optimizer will use table stats and tricky operations (and cached I/O) to retrieve the necessary data. You should try adding this index, and see if it makes your Oracle query [any] faster.